# explicitly set redirect_uri in keycloak java adapters for oidc

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I noticed that there is no config setting for the redirect_uri used with the keycloak java adapters: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/java-adapter-config.html

The lib seems to try to figure out the correct value, but is there another way to explicitly set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way in the Java adapters to accomplish this. With the JS adapter, this is possible.

The Java adapters derieve the redirect URI from the path of the currently accessed, but "secured" resource.

But of course you are free to "patch" (aka: overwrite) the resp. Keycloak adapter classes or build your own adapter, as KC is open source...